# What causes the </xxxxelmt> to appear?

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a problem in one of my ASP.NET Page.

I'm copying the content of an old ASPX page from our old application (.NET 1.1)

to a new aspx page (.NET 4.0) but whenever i hit save or view the designer.

some weird tags are being generated  which is `</xxxxelmt>`

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: It might help if you showed the tags in context.

Comment: i think its some `<hr>` and `<td>` tags

Comment: Ah. I wonder if you have an xhtml doctype set, and it's using that as a generic closing tag to help the document pass a (nearly) valid xml.

Comment: I think i found it.. it will generate `</xxxxelmt>` if it has unclosed tags.. to pass the page validation.